# Compound Primary Key

Tags: f#

So this is pretty straight forward. I can't seem to find an answer for this on the web.

In Fluent Migrator, I see the option to tag a column with PrimaryKey() but I don't see anything for creating compound primary keys. It doesn't look like there's an overload for PrimaryKey either.

Is this possible?

```
base.Create.Table(tableName).WithColumn("Id").AsGuid().PrimaryKey().NotNullable().Unique()
                .WithColumn("c1").AsGuid().NotNullable().Unique()
                .WithColumn("c2").AsString().NotNullable()
                .WithColumn("c3").AsString().NotNullable()
                .WithColumn("c4").AsDateTime()
                |> ignore
```

In this example I'd like to use `c2` and `c3` as a composite primary key

Comment: Which library are you using? Your sample looks like FluentMigrator syntax

Comment: @ChadGilbert yeah I think that's it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In FluentMigrator, you can create a composite primary key like this:

```
Create.PrimaryKey("PK_Table").OnTable("Table").WithSchema("schemaname")
    .Columns([|"Col1"; "Col2"|])
    |> ignore
```

Comment: I used something like this 
`base.Create.PrimaryKey("KeyName").OnTable(tableName).Columns([|"";""|]) |> ignore`

Answer (score 5):

I seem to remember you could just apply the `PrimaryKey()` method to multiple columns. So to use c2 and c3 as a composite primary key for example:

```
base.Create.Table(tableName)
    .WithColumn("Id").AsGuid().NotNullable().Unique()
    .WithColumn("c1").AsGuid().NotNullable().Unique()
    .WithColumn("c2").AsString().NotNullable().PrimaryKey()
    .WithColumn("c3").AsString().NotNullable().PrimaryKey()
    .WithColumn("c4").AsDateTime()
    |> ignore
```